# OpenDayLight DLUX login: Unable to Login

Tags: ubuntu, server, opendaylight, sdn

This seems to be a common issue but I haven't found a solution that actually works. I've tried installing both Lithium and Helium on Ubuntu using the Installation Guide from the wiki. Following this guide the only feature that gets installed is odl-l2switch-switch-ui which should also install the DLUX Web Interface. I can access it fine using http://:8181/index.html but I get the 'Unable to Login' error when i try to log in using admin / admin. I've tried the various fixes that include installing several features in the correct order. And I've deleted the data directory, then reinstalled the features, but I cannot get it to log in. I am installing on Ubuntu Server, not on Ubuntu Desktop. It seems unlikely that that's causing the issue but it's worth noting.

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 - same result. I'm starting to think DLUX is a myth.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and I solved it using following method.

Enter following commands in sequence.

1. Logout from OpendayLight by hitting "ctrl+d" or "logout" or "system:shutdown"
2. Then run './bin/karaf clear'
3. Get yourself again login to the OpendayLight through following command

   ./bin/karaf
4. Then run the following command

   feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs  odl-dlux-core

I hope it would solve login problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem with Beryllium version
The only solution worked for me till now is run karaf with clean parameter

```
./karaf clean
```

and then reinstall all required features using

```
"feature:install odl:dlux:all" and  
"feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-dlux-core"
```

After this it was working fine for me.These packages may differ according to your installed karaf package

Answer (score 1):

Running `./bin/karaf clean` and `feature:install odl-restconf-all odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-all features-dlux features-dluxapps` in the karaf console worked for me as well with ODL Oxygen 0.8.4. It seems that the feature installing order matters.

Comment: It doesn't work in ODL Sodium. Cause there are only `odl-dlux-core` and `odl-restconf`existed. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Tbh friend. I gave up ODL cause I had a tight deadline. The whole feature thing is too complicated. Features come and go in a strange way. I ended up using ryu controller which handles the various modules more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, I was able to get it working on Ubuntu Desktop. Here are the exact steps I used to build it.

//Install JDK and Maven

## `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

## `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/apache-maven`

## `wget http://ftp.wayne.edu/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz`

## `sudo mv apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz /usr/local/apache-maven`

## `sudo tar -xzvf /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz -C /usr/local/apache-maven/`

## `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mvn mvn /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn 1`

## `sudo update-alternatives --config mvn`

## `sudo apt-get install vim`

## `vim ~/.bashrc`

//add these lines to the end of /.bashrc

## `export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3`

## `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"`

## `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

//build ODL

## `sudo apt-get install git`

## `git clone https://github.com/opendaylight/integration.git`

## `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml --create-dirs -o ~/.m2/settings.xml`

## `cd integration`

## `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

//install OpenVSwitch

## `sudo apt-get install openvswitch-switch`

//Run ODL

## `cd distributions/karaf/target/assembly/bin`

## `./karaf -of13`

//use ./karaf clean -of13 if it hangs

//install features IN THIS ORDER

## `feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-dlux-core`

Answer (score 0):

i have met the same question. i can login via  http://localip:8181/dlux/index.html ;but can't login via  http://localhost:9000/DLUX/index.html.
   please check if your ip address has changed? under this folder dlux/dlux-web/config,there is a JSON file development.json. replace the ip address with your current ip.
   mine is working fine.wish you good luck!